# AWS Cognito is not sending a validation sms or email for the user upon signup

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-cognito

I have a react native project. I am currently in the process of adding aws cognito and aws amplify into my project. I have a signup screen in which user fills in all the required information including `username, email, password, phone, first name, last name, full name, and locale.` When a user confirms signup, it navigates to the `ConfirmNewAccountScreen`. My issues is that right now, no sms mesage or email is sent to the user for verification so I can not verify the user.

I do see all of the information for the signup when I check the user pool in my AWS console.

Here is what it looks like when the user confirms their signup:

```
async function handleSignUp(){

    try {
      await signUp({
        username,
        password,
        options: {
          userAttributes: {
            email: email,
            phone_number: `+1${phone}`, 
            given_name: firstName,
            family_name: lastName,
            nickname: firstName,
            name: `${firstName} ${lastName}`,
            locale: location,
            'custom:followers': '0',
            'custom:following': '0',
            'custom:favorites': '0'
          }
        }
      });
      navigation.navigate('ConfirmNewAccountScreen', {username:username})
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error signing up:', error);
    }
  }
```

It then redirects properly to the  `ConfirmNewSignUpScreen`

I have a domain setup so that it allows me to send SMS and Email but I am not getting anything when testing it.

They are valid emails and the number is formatted `+1##########`

[image: domain setup]

[image: user pool]

[image: signup settings]